# difflib output is very strange, adding extra whitespace on each character

Tags: python, difflib

I'm playing around with difflib in Python and I'm having some difficulty getting the output to look good.  For some strange reason, difflib is adding a single whitespace before each character.  For example, I have a file (textfile01.txt) that looks like this:

> test text which has no meaning

and textfile02.txt

> test text which has no meaning
>
> but looks nice

Here's a small code sample for how I'm trying to accomplish the comparison:

```
import difflib

handle01 = open(text01.txt , 'r')
handle02 = open(text02.txt , 'r')

d = difflib.ndiff( handle01.read() , handle02.read() )
print "".join(list(diff))
```

Then, I get this ugly output that looks...very strange:

> t  e  s  t     t  e  x  t     w  h  i  c  h     h  a  s     n  o     m  e  a  n  i  n  g-
>
> - b- u- t-  - l- o- o- k- s-  - n- i- c- e

As you can see, the output looks horrible.  I've just been following basic difflib tutorials I found online, and according to those, the output should look completely different.  I have no clue what I'm doing wrong.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`difflib.ndiff` compares lists of strings, but you are passing strings to them — and a string is really a list of characters. The function is thus comparing the strings *character by character.*

```
>>> list(difflib.ndiff("test", "testa"))
['  t', '  e', '  s', '  t', '+ a']
```

(Literally, you can go from the list `["t", "e", "s", "t"]` to the list `["t", "e", "s", "t", "a"]` by adding the element `["a"]` there.

You want to change `read()` to `readlines()` so you can compare the two files in a linewise fashion, which is probably what you were expecting.

You also want to change `"".join(...` to `"\n".join(...` in order to get a `diff`-like output on screen.

```
>>> list(difflib.ndiff(["test"], ["testa"]))
['- test', '+ testa', '?     +\n']
>>> print "\n".join(_)
- test
+ testa
?     +
```

(Here difflib is being extra nice and marking the exact position where the character was added in the `?` line.)

Comment: That fixed it.  I didn't realize it was looking for a list of strings.  Most of the examples I was looking at "appeared" to be using normal strings.  Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: indeed, the officiel example on the official handbook use string...https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.Differ